# Solution how to import contents of a .txt file into a body field?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, nodes

Are any solution how we can import **content of text** (.txt) file with feeds into **body field**?

We don't have any problem with standard feeds import with CSV file and files into field file. We just need solution how we can import content of separate text file into body field.

Thanks

Comment: Just one file? Copy-paste. TXT file referenced in CSV? How? Please add some details about the structure of what you have.

Comment: There are more than 10.000 files

with one csv files we have follow data

title, tags, image_file, body
====================================
"ModelOfCar", "Type", "car_image.jpg", "text_to_body.txt"

So when we import we need content of file text_to_body.txt import into body.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish this with [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) and a [custom plugin](https://www.drupal.org/node/1246602).

Take one of the existing text plugins and clone it to a new one.  Then inside the plugin callback, take the cell value (your text file name), build up a proper path, do a [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), and stuff the contents into the result.

If you end up going this route, it may be a decent patch to Feeds Tamper for inclusion in the project itself.